# call c function in running app from web service

Tags: webserver, cgi, rpc, named-pipes

I have a web server running on a RaspberryPI. The web server is supposed to provide an interface to a program that deals with a connected 3D printing hardware.

How can I create an element on the web page, that triggers via the web server a function inside an already running C program?

More details:

The printer management app is written in C/C++ and runs all the time, providing a few buttons on a touch screen. The web interface will provide an upload button for printing files, a few status informations, and a start/pause/stop button.

I know a lot about C/C++ and the Unix RPC or named-pipe API. However, I know little about HTML and all the associates ways of scripting and communicationg with the web server.

What is the best approach to implement the start/stop button on the web page, so that a function inside my printer controller is triggered, and secondly, how can I get data back from the printer controller onto the web page?

Thanks!